# Installation instructions for HP 7 tablet (also called 'Mesquite')

Tags: dual-boot, hardware-compatibility

I'm looking at the HP 7 at Walmart (http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-7-Tablet-Intel-Atom-Processor-with-8GB-Memory-featuring-Android-4.1-Jelly-Bean/27618120), but I don't want to purchase it unless I can install linux on it (ie: not chroot).

Has anyone successfully installed a linux distro on it? If so, how? I'm assuming it's EFI, but confirmation would help.

Comment: I've been googling for ~ 1 hour and have found nothing about this. I would suspect that maybe you could jailbreak it, since it's an Android device, but that just get's you into Cyanogen Mod territory. Given the lack of info I'd keep looking for a different device, must my $0.02.

Comment: That processor would seem to be able to support Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(system_on_chip)

Comment: That was my thinking as well and unfortunately I have had the same luck as far as figuring out how a different system could be loaded onto it. It's really a shame as it's very, very hard to find reasonably-priced tablets and it's not like you can buy one with linux preloaded (non-android linux, that is :P) Any suggestions?

Comment: None that I've seen thus far: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTUxNTc

Comment: There is this reddit thread too: http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1r9rkn/what_is_the_status_of_non_android_linux_on_tablets/. One thing I will mention is that I've heard ppl talk about all these knock-off devices that do run Linux abroad (I live in US), but I haven't taken the time to research these. But often times you can find these devices on Ebay, where you're effectively ordering it from the backdoor of a factory, but I know of ppl doing that w/ monitors and the quality is excellent.

Comment: Thanks. That's the most helpful information I've seen so far.